# SIGSEGV error on Tomcat 7 on CentOS with problematic frame libkrb5.so.3

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, ldap, segmentation-fault

I have a `Tomcat 7.47` running on `java 1.7.0_65`. The server I am using is a virtual machine using VMWare, so it cannot be a hardware error and runs `CentOS 6.5`

I created an online chat-tool using the websocket api and my authentification is based on LDAP. The user-information is also received via LDAP using `Apache LDAP`.

Everything works quite well, but once in a while the whole JVM crashes with a SIGSEGV error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f778ad0a040, pid=12392, tid=140151424538368
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b17) (build 1.7.0_65-mockbuild_2014_07_16_06_06-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libkrb5.so.3+0x29a040]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
```

The full error.log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/gCcCqqVf)

I already tried increasing the memory without success. Next I tried changing the LDAP Library because I thought maybe my previous library `UnboundID` has some problems with `libkrb5.so.3` on CentOS but `Apache LDAP` doesn't work either

I also tried running it with the same java version and the same tomcat version on an Ubuntu laptop and here everything worked fine.

Is there any known bug with `libkrb5.so.3` on CentOS?

Comment: This looks like a bug with Kerberos, or possible with the component calling it. Can you post more of the crash log? It should have a back-trace of even the native code.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz under the code block is a link to the full error.log - do you need anything else?

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that. The dump really adds nothing to my (mostly) untrained eye. This looks like a bug in `libkrb` to me.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz okay, thank you! I guess I will try to change the OS as it works on Ubuntu

Comment: What are the versions on the two systems? CentOS is pretty stable...

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz CentOS 6.5 and Ubuntu 12 and 14 (both work)

Comment: Sorry... I meant the version of libkrb on all those systems.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz on CentOS it should be 3.3 and on Ubuntu it is the same (I guess the numbers after the library name is the version?)

Comment: On Ubuntu try `krb5-config --version` (or, if that doesn't work, try  `dpkg -S /usr/lib/*/libkrb*` and then `apt-cache show [package]` for whatever packages are shown). On CentoOS, try `yum info krb5-libs.i686` or similar. The version numbers on all the systems I tried has krb5 installed at version 1.10 - 1.12. Not sure what you're running and where...

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz ah okay. Ubuntu: 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4 
CentOS: 1.10.3

Comment: Okay. At this point, I can't really help any more. Make sure you have latest versions of everything you can get, then re-test. If it's still broken, try Googling for "libkrb java crash" or something  like that.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz okay. Thanks for trying! I will try to update everything and if it doesn't work I will go on searching for other solutions.